How do I streamline the Kudu logs to a fileshare in a storage account?
I need to streamline the kudu logs or exposed the kudo logs to another sharing folder like a storage account. I have set up the Diagnostic and App service logs to my storage account, however, it looks different from what the kudu logs has. Thanks in advance.
Already set up the Diagnostic and app service logs but the logging in kudu is different
enter image description here

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
